# How to get all rows data in single row in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having MYSQL table "users" with two  fields

```
1. id
2. name
```

I am fetching records in Codeigniter something like,

```
id   name
1.   jhon
2.   martina
3.   Rob
```

But I want results in single row like,

```
"john,martina,Rob"
```

Comment: its a simple codiegniter query
$this->db->select('name')->from('users')->get();

Comment: Please show me than I will make you understand more.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT("name") as all_names', false)->from('table')->get()->row_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MYSQL query here,

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(users.name) AS name
FROM users
```

This will return something like,

```
userA,Userb,UserC
```

Here is the way for a raw query in Codeigniter,

```
function get_names () {
    $query = "  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(users.name) AS name FROM users";
    return $this->db->query($query)->row();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getName(){
    $this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(users.name) AS name');
    $q =$this->db->get('users');
    if($q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
    foreach($q->result() as $row)
    {
        $output =$row->name;
    }               
    return $output;
}
}
```